# How to preload Enscripten generated function

Tags: svelte, webassembly, preload

I've been struggling to create a component with <script context='module'> to preload an Enscripten-generated function. After some reading, I tried preload() function but then realized it only applies for Sapper not Svelte. I got some advice to do this with generic index.html file which works fine, but I'm not able to "componentize" it. The body in index.html file is

```
<body>
    <script type="module">
        function loadLib() {
          const script = document.createElement("script");
          script.src = "coolprop.js";
          script.async = true;
  
          document.body.appendChild(script);
  
          return new Promise(resolve => {
            script.onload = async () => {
              const m = window.Module;
              if (m.onRuntimeInitialized) resolve(m); // Already initialized.
              m.onRuntimeInitialized = () => resolve(m);
            };
          });
        }
        const coolproLib = await loadLib();
        console.log("density is ",coolproLib.PropsSI('Dmass', 'T', (20+273.15), 'P', 1000*6894.76,'Xenon' ))
      </script>
</body>
```

Any help to make it a svelte component would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Gani --

Comment: When do you want to execute the function `loadLib ` exactly? If it's on the component render just call it in an `onMount` callback.

Comment: @johannchopin, I was able to call it in an onMount, but because it is a module, I'm not able to do reactive calculations like changing temperature for example and seeing values update. Any idea how to use loadLib outside the onMount call?